# Return Data form a Ajax

Tags: ajax

I have the function

```
 function Get_Data(FileName) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: FileName,
        data: "{}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (jsonData) {
            alert("OK " + jsonData); // alert box1
            return jsonData;
        },
        error: function () {
            alert('Error loading');
            return "";
        }
    });
}
```

in a function I have

`var SS = Get_Data('Min_Required.asp?id=' + ID);`

```
alert('ID = ' + SS[0].ID +  ' SuppleName ' + SS[0].Sname); //alert box 2
```

I know the data this there 
if i put `Min_Required.asp?id=29` in the address bar i get

```
[{"ID":10,"Sname":"Farm"}]      :)
```

when it runs

message box `(alert box1)` saying OK "[object Object]" which is the alert in the Get_Data function

but the secord message box does not show :( :(

What am I missing?

Comment: AJAX calls are asynchronous so the value is already returned before your ajax call finishes. if you want function to return ajax response then you need to make synchronous AJAX request.

Comment: Making synchronous ajax calls will solve your issue, but not might be a best practice, you should be a little bit more specific on what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `async:false,` as parameter to ajax call.

Comment: Thanks I had to put the return at the end of the function;

Answer (score 0):

The ajax call in the function 'Get_Data' is asynchronous. The first alert message will be called when the ajax call completes successfully and other alert message which is outside the 'Get_Data' function, running separately.

It is similar to threading when the ajax call and the current process running on separate threads.

To make the required thing possible, either make ajax call asynchronous

```
async:false
```

or put the second alert message call inside the success callback of the ajax call.